# NPM Azure Pipeline - Missing script

Tags: angular, azure, npm, azure-pipelines

I have included a custom script in package.json.
I'm using it to run after npm install.
But it says that it cannot locate the script.
I dont understand why because it runs just fine from my local machine. This is currently happening while I'm trying to deploy through Azure Pipelines.

```
"build": "ng build",
"buildprod": "ng build --prod",
```

Comment: How do you run the script? Is the Workingdirectory correct?

Comment: Yes, the folder containing package.json

Comment: @Info Chorus Can you share your pipeline definition and the log containing the error message? This will help further investigation

Comment: @Info Chorus Do you use this command `npm run-script build`?